# htaccess redirect subfolders also

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am new to htaccess rules. I have tried to search about my questionm but couldn't get the answer, so I am writing the question here.

I have the following htaccess file in my root folder of my php application

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

Now if I add any sub-folder images/ I get the error stating "URL not found". I suspect some of the htaccess rules is causing this.

I would really appreciate if someone could explain me the cause.

Thank you,

Comment: You could perhaps explain what you are trying to achieve with the redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rewrite condition is applying every url to your domain. What you can do exclude image files from this. I think using this will help

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(images)
```